# This C program gives zero average.Whats wrong in it?

Tags: c, average, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    {
        float test1Marks, test2Marks, test3Marks, averageMarks;
        averageMarks = (test1Marks + test2Marks + test3Marks) / 3;

        printf("Test 1 Marks:");
        scanf("%f", &test1Marks);

        printf("Test 2 Marks:");
        scanf("%f", &test2Marks);

        printf("Test 3 Marks:");
        scanf("%f", &test3Marks);

        printf("Average Marks of tests are:%f", averageMarks);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Everything alright but the final output which gives average is wrong.
But when I assign values to two of the variables and input third ones value by scanf syntax then it gives the average otherwise not.

Comment: You need to read values into your variables *before* computing the average.

Comment: Possibly not going to help future readers...

Comment: For most of the stack overflow users this question may be too basic :)

Comment: Why do you have two pairs of curly braces?

Comment: Am new to programming

Comment: I used two pairs because before that I had another another different program written in it so I used two pairs of brackets around each code to separate them and another third one(that you mentioned) for return value which would apply to all program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move `averageMarks=(test1Marks+test2Marks+test3Marks)/3;` *after the last* `scanf` but *before* the `print` statement in which you are printing the average!

```
int main()
{
    float test1Marks,test2Marks,test3Marks,averageMarks;

    printf("Test 1 Marks:");
    scanf("%f",&test1Marks);

    printf("Test 2 Marks:");
    scanf("%f",&test2Marks);

    printf("Test 3 Marks:");
    scanf("%f",&test3Marks);

    /* Now with determined test1Marks, test2Marks, and test3Marks
       values we can compute their average:
    */
    averageMarks=(test1Marks+test2Marks+test3Marks)/3;

    printf("Average Marks of tests are:%f",averageMarks);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `test1Marks` is uninitialize, not necessarily 0.  Attempting to read `test1Marks` before initialization/assignment is UB.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read values into your variables before computing the average [@John Bode 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197154/this-c-program-always-gives-zero-average-whats-wrong-in-it#comment77361749_45197154)

Compute `averageMarks=(test1Marks+test2Marks+test3Marks)/3;` after the values are read.

In another language this approach may work, yet C requires sequential evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

`averageMarks=(test1Marks+test2Marks+test3Marks)/3;` is not a function, it is a series of statements to do something, where it adds the values in those variable *at the time it is run*, and then divides by 3, and assigns the result to averageMarks.

when you read in the values, `scanf` puts whatever value it reads into the variables when it is executed, and then you print out the `averageMarks`, which was already computed and stored earlier with the empty variables you made with the first statement.